# How to disable drop for all elements of page except 2 div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a page (created not by me) with two divs. This divs contains some span elements, they can be drag&dropped between this divs. This functionality implemented using jQuery draggable and droppable function. But user is able to drop span element not only at div, but at any place of page. Question is: how can I prevent this? I need to disable dropping span at any place except this divs. Dragged span should return to place where it was taken.

Can I make it with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`revert`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert) option of the draggables to `invalid` so that they return to their original position if not dropped on a compatible droppable.

The droppables should also have the [`accept`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) option suitably set to accept the draggables.